# Asyc Web Service/HTTPS call not working in Titanium mobile?

Tags: mobile, titanium, httpclient, appcelerator-mobile

We are using more than one Web Service( `HTTPS` call) to get data from server.
We are uploading a file to server in a Web Service and at same time we are making another Web Service call to get/send data to/from the same server.

But we are not getting response from 2nd Web service till first Web service (upload receipt) succeed or failed.
So our doubt is how Titanium send Web service call when more than one Web service send from the Titanium Application.

Is the web service call from the Titanium app queued (Sync)or is it called in parallel to other Web service (Async call)?

In our Titanium app we are creating a new `HTTPClient` object for each Web service call,  using the following code to create a new `HTTPClient` object:

```
function runService(){   
  var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var r = this.responseText; 
  }
  xhr.open("GET", URI);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass `true` for async

```
xhr.open("GET", URI, true);
```